# angular 2 service extention: change datatype in function

Tags: angular, angular-services

In my project I have created list.service.ts that holds any functionality to lists, from loading list of json objects from API, mapping API results to rows, paginations and so on...

For each list type (users, projects...) I extend this service with extra data, properies and functionality.

```
export class UsersListService extends ListsService {...}
```

Of all changes in extended services, API result format (data type) changes.

My MapData function (general) looks like this:

```
MapData(resultsData: any[], columns: NgListColumns[]): NgListDataRow[] {...}
```

Function in user-list service would look like this:

```
MapData(resultsData: UserApiData[], columns: NgListColumns[]): NgListDataRow[] {...}
```

So the only change is that data type for resultsData.

The same chanage will be applied to a few other functions.

**My question: Is there any way to have this data type as parameter in main service and have this applied in extended services automatically?**

Right now I have to rewrite all these functions in service extentions, but this forces me to keep track of any changes to these functions in main service and fixing all copies of these functions in all extended services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the concept of generics in TypeScript.

Try something like this in your general `ListsService`

```
// T will be a type that the consuming "component" will specify when using this method
MapData<T>(resultsData: T[], columns: NgListColumns[]): NgListDataRow[] { ... }
```

Then to use your method, you would do:

```
// the <...> here populates the type of the generic when we are consuming it
this.userListService.MapData<UserApiData>(x, y, z);
```

This way (I assume) you don't have to duplicate methods just to have the type right.

Learn more about generics [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-generic).

Comment: Yesterday I read about conditional types and tried declaring ApiDataType = any in genera service then overwriting it in extended services with ApiDataType = UserApiData. However your solution with using generics seems the correct one. Thanks.